# WearableListenerService onMessageReceived is not called on device

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I am trying to send a simple message from my Android wear app to my phone app using the `Wearable.MessageApi`.

This is my `onConnected` callback from GoogleApiClient on the Wear device.

```
final PendingResult<Status> status = Wearable.DataApi.addListener(googleApiClient, this);
status.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(Status status) {
        if (!status.isSuccess()) {
            return;
        }

        NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes =
                Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(googleApiClient).await();
        for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
            System.out.println("Sending message: " + node.getDisplayName());
            final MessageApi.SendMessageResult result =
                    Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(googleApiClient, node.getId(),
                            "request", "12345".getBytes())
                            .await();
            System.out.println("sent: " + result.getStatus().isSuccess());
        }
    }
});
```

And this is displaying the following when ran

```
Sending message: Nexus 6P
sent: true
```

And this is my registered service on my app:

```
public class MyWearableListenerService extends WearableListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Received message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPeerConnected(Node peer) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Peer connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I properly verified that the `Peer connected` toast is showing up when the emulator is connected to my device. I properly did the port forwarding to debug on wear emulator. I checked that my applicationId and package names are consistent across my app and wear app. However, I never get the `onMessageReceived` callback on my device.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! I've been debugging this for a whole day now :(

Comment: Please have a look at this gist. It may help you to fix your issue
https://gist.github.com/schwiz/84f14c94d4a95c3b77be

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've checked everything against your gist, the only difference is that I am trying to send message from wear to device whereas you are trying to send it from device to wear. I don't think that would impact anything though.

Comment: Alright. Let's do some magic. Try  MANUALLY  uninstall your app apk on both devices .. and test it again

Comment: tried, no luck :( uninstalled and reinstalled (app first, then wear) on both devices.. gah, pretty sure its just some configuration thats messed up which is causing the message to be dropped. i wish there is more logging :\

Comment: Please checkout this library.. It's kinda thin layer for WearbleApi https://github.com/Mariuxtheone/Teleport
Its source may be helpful for you

Comment: Thanks for all the help @ProblemSlover! I figured out my problem -___- stupid dev builds..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oh, good god.. I figured out my problem. I THOUGHT the applicationId was the same, but it turned out that I never set up build flavors on the wear module, so the two applicationIds were actually `com.example.android` and `com.example.android.dev`..

Hope this helps other people who ran into the same problem as me :\

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue, due to (very) poor and outdated documentation on the Android Developer website. I was adding a Wear app to an existing app that's been around for years. As such, I have been using a custom debug.keystore for years now in my main app.

When I made the Wear app, I did not update the build.gradle to use the same debug.keystore file as the regular app - once I did that, I started receiving messages from the Watch -> Phone!

Here is a checklist to review if you're having the same issue as me and the OP:

1. Wear and Phone apps need same applicationId
2. Same versionNumber and versionName between apps
3. Signed by the same key (this was what fixed my issue)

I just copied the "signingConfigs" section from my app's build.gradle to the wear app's build.gradle

`signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file('../app/debug.keystore')
    }
}`

This issue cost me an entire day, hopefully someone else finds this useful.

Comment: Thanks a ton. The documentation really needs to be more clear on this.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes, thank you so much!!

Comment: In my case, it was the version code and version name not matching. Many hours checking what could be wrong and finally it was simply this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

also struggeld with the same problem..

Make sure that you use at least version 18.0.0 in the wear module!

build.gradle:

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:18.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible trap, in your WearableListenerService, don't forget the call to super:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate(); // <-- don't forget this
    ...
}
```