# WearableListenerService onMessageReceived not working

Tags: android, android-service, wear-os

I am sending messages from my phone to the Wear. I want to be able to receive messages even when the wear activity is closed.

I wrote a small service which launches my main Activity (UI) if it receives a message. However, the onMessageReceived function never gets called in the WearableListenerService. I also tried the sample code at [this tutorial](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/a-guide-to-the-android-wear-message-api/152), but it doesn't seem to work for me.

What I have tried so far:

1. Other threads posted on SO with the same problem mentioned issues with
   applicationId in mobile and wear module. The applicationId is the same in both modules.
2. I tried writing the messageReceived function within the Activity, and it works as long as the activity is open (which is the expected behavior).
3. I know that I don't have to launch the WearableListenerService, it automatically gets started upon receiving a message, but I explicitly tried launching it from the activity, as a last attempt. The service does get created, but the onMessageReceived() function doesn't work. It doesn't even reach the function (tested by putting logs).
4. I also tried making it a regular background service (as you would in Android), copy the communication part to service, but to no avail.

Here is the code:

Wear Manifest:

```
  <service android:name=".MessageService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CAPABILITY_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CHANNEL_EVENT" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/prefix" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

MessageService:

```
public class MessageService extends WearableListenerService {
public Handler h;
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Log.i("service", "im here");

}
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    Log.i("onMessageReceived","im here!");
        Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
        intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
        startActivity( intent );

       }
```

The code the Main Activity in Wear and the main activity on mobile is from [this example.](https://github.com/djurovski/wearable-message-api-example).

The communication within the activity works, the service is not working. Help?

Comment: You can try to check this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817622/wearablelistenerservice-onmessagereceived-is-not-called-on-device), maybe it is the same problem of yours. The caused in this problem is because of [build flavor](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) on the wear module. You can also check this [github](https://gist.github.com/schwiz/84f14c94d4a95c3b77be), it is same scenario of yours, in where you want to send message from phone to wear device.

Comment: I'd try paring back your `intent-filter`. Do you really need `DATA_CHANGED`, `CAPABILITY_CHANGED`, and all the rest? Try cutting it back to just `MESSAGE_RECEIVED`. Also, is `/prefix` your correct path? Looks like a sample prefix from a tutorial somewhere.

Comment: @KENdi I did check out that question. Like I mentioned in my original post, applicationId is not the problem, which is the accepted answer in that question. I checked build properties as well, and I don't see any issues.

Comment: @String: I only had MESSAGE_RECEIVED to begin with, I just added the others as an attempt in the dark (which obviously didn't work). Also, adding more filters than needed shouldn't prevent it from functioning, correct?

Comment: Sure, adding more `action` filters **shouldn't** break anything - but we're trying to diagnose something that, on the face of it, should be working. Cutting out anything extraneous is one approach to doing that. What about the `android:pathPrefix`?

Comment: @String Gotcha. The prefix was another hollow attempt. I removed all the extraneous permissions and the prefix line as well, the problem persists.

Comment: If I'd genuinely believed that the prefix was the problem, I would have put it as an answer, not a comment. There are a dozen things that can go wrong with the Wear APIs, we're just trying to figure out which is the problem in your case - and from what you've posted, the `intent-filter` looked likely.

Comment: @String Yes I understand that. Maybe, I misspoke. I meant to say that the prefix was a hollow attempt on my part to fix the issue, as were the extraneous intent filters. I removed them, but it's still not working. Any more ideas, mate?

Answer (score 0):

The message path in the mobile app has to match that in the intent filter of the service. You have this as '/prefix' in the intent filter but is 'message1' or 'message2' in the mobile app.