# Android handheld and wearable not receiving messages

Tags: android, android-service, wear-os

I'm trying to send a message from a wearable to a handheld and then a response from the handheld to the wearable (both modules use the same code and logic).
**Gradle**:

```
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0-alpha2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.6.1'
```

...

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

**AndroidManifest**:

```
    <application>
    ...
        <service android:name=".ReceiverService"
                 android:enabled="true"
                 android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED"/>
                <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>    
    </application>
```

**ReceiverService**:

```
public class ReceiverService extends WearableListenerService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        super.onMessageReceived(messageEvent);
        Log.v(TAG, "onMessageReceived: " + messageEvent);
    }
}
```

**MessageSender**:

```
public class MessageSender implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "_wear_message_sender";
    private final GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private static class InstanceHolder {
        private static final MessageSender sInstance = new MessageSender();
    }

    private MessageSender() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(WearApp.getInstance().getContext())
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    public static MessageSender getInstance() {
        return InstanceHolder.sInstance;
    }

    public void sendMessage(final String path, final String message) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.blockingConnect(Constants.GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_TIMEOUT_S, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }    
                List<Node> nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await().getNodes();
                Log.d(TAG, "Nodes count " + nodes.size());

                for (Node node : nodes) {
                    Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), path, message.getBytes()).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "sendMessage(" + path + "): " + sendMessageResult.getStatus().isSuccess());
                        }
                    });
                }
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            }
        }).start();
    }
    ...
}
```

And I got this output:

> D/_wear_message_sender: onConnected: null
>   D/_wear_message_sender: Nodes count 1
>   D/_wear_message_sender: sendMessage(/test): true

I've used a Moto 360 and Emulator, the message is sent but the handheld `WearableListenerService` `onMessageReceived()` is not called. Same goes the other way, I've sent a message from a mobile phone and the wearable `onMessageReceived` is not called.
What am I missing here?

Comment: @Blackbelt it's now deprecated: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/bind-listener

Comment: Check if the [`applicationID`](https://plus.google.com/+PetrN%C3%A1levka/posts/deCyoF6ALvV) were the same in the build.gradle for mobile and wear app because otherwise Android wouldn't know to which the messages should be sent. You can check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817622/wearablelistenerservice-onmessagereceived-is-not-called-on-device). Also make sure that the `buildTypes` part and the `signingConfigs` part are the same in both apps.

Comment: @abielita thanks, I had different packages name indeed. Now it's working but only 50% because I can send messages from the handheld to the watch but not the other way. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @abielita, found out the problem, I've commented a few lines in my app manifest. Now it's working 100%. Post your comment as answer and I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if the [`applicationID`](https://plus.google.com/+PetrN%C3%A1levka/posts/deCyoF6ALvV) were the same in the build.gradle for mobile and wear app because otherwise Android wouldn't know to which the messages should be sent. You can check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817622/wearablelistenerservice-onmessagereceived-is-not-called-on-device). Also make sure that the `buildTypes` part and the `signingConfigs` part are the same in both apps.

Comment: Thanks! I've had different applicationIDs. Solved it.